# How do I publish subproject to Maven with subprojects buildscript gradle version？

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I want to publish some subproject to maven by using maven-publish plugin. The current Gradle script looks like this.

```
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    group "com.huawei.quickapp"
    version "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    publishing {
        publications {
            publishTask(MavenPublication) {
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = uri("${rootDir}/local_repo/repos/")
            }
        }
    }
}
static Boolean publishIfNeeded(taskName){
    println("name = " + taskName)
    def list = ["baselibrary", "corelibrary"]
    if (taskName in list) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

I just want two libraries,core and base to be published. When I submitted the code to the pipeline, the CI suggested that the NDK version did not match, but there was no NDK-related configuration in my code. The upgrade is necessary because only versions greater than 3.6 support the use of From Components.Debug or some other build variable in gradle script.I tried configuring the build script for Subproject separately like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}
subprojects {
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```

but it still not work. I got this error

```
Could not get unknown property 'Debug' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.
```

Is there a way to publish a submodule using the buildScripte of a submodule? thx.

Comment: The CI error is : No version of NDK matched the requested version 21.0.6113669. Versions available locally: 20.1.5948944

Comment: Did you get solution?

Comment: Yes, This can be solved by specifying ndkVersion in build.gradle。